# How might I add a fade in/fade out on hover using HTML5 data attributes?

Tags: jquery, html, image

I'm trying to grasp how I might use jQuery to change the image source to a second image using html data attributes on hover, with a fadeOut/fadeIn effect.

It would look like this:

1. On hover, first image fades out.
2. Second image from data-alt-src is faded in.
3. On mouse out, it fades back to first image from original src.

Here's what I have so far in the DOM:

```
<img class="myimageclass" src="http://www.example.com/path-to/picture.jpg" data-alt-src="http://www.example.com/path-to/picture-alt.jpg" alt="my picture">
```

Any suggestions on the best way to implement this?

EDIT: Here's the JavaScript I have so far, and I've been able to get the image to swap, but where I get stuck is firing the fadeIn/fadeOut methods :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var sourceSwap = function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
        $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
        $this.attr('src', newSource);
}

$(function () {
    $('img.myimgclass').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: you might want to have a look at hoverintent plugin http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html . The default jQuery hover handler have some reacting issues.

Comment: I just edited my question and added the JavaScript I'm working with right now!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".myimageclass").hover(function () {

    $(this).fadeOut(2000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        var temp = this.getAttribute("data-src");
        this.setAttribute("data-src", this.src);
        this.src = temp;
        $(this).fadeIn(2000);
    }, 2000);

},

function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(2000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        var temp = this.getAttribute("data-src");
        this.setAttribute("data-src", this.src);
        this.src = temp;
        $(this).fadeIn(2000);
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I implemented your snippet, but I'm running into a bit of an issue. I get the following error: 

 `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined` 

This is on lines 5 and 16 (`var temp = this.dataset.src;`)

Comment: void, I spoke too soon!

I'm still getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the `var temp = this.getAttribute("data-src");` line, and it's pointing to an anonymous function.